# Django with postgresql, the datetime microsecond's leading 0 is disappeared

Tags: python, django, postgresql, datetime, psycopg2

I'm trying to retrieve `datetime` typed data from postgresql on django.

But if the microsecond has leading 0, like below

```
|        datetime_field        |
|2021-06-07 09:22:13.099866+00 |
```

the result is shown as

```
datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 7, 9, 22, 13, 998660, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

in Python.

Take notice of microsecond 099866. It has been changed to 998660.

If I insert the resulted datetime object without any change to postgresql, it is uploaded as below.

```
|        datetime_field        |
| 2021-06-07 09:22:13.99866+00 |
```

The 0 at the head is disappeared.

It seems this problem is derived from psycopg2, not just django but I can't find any resolution for this.

How can I get the microseconds in its entierty?

p.s. Welcome for editing for just the English. As I'm not an English speaker, I'm not sure whether I wrote correct expressions.

---

Addition of the exact step.

I'm doing the job on docker containers. Two containers are used now, each for django server and PostgreSQL server.

```
Version infos:
Python 3.9.1
Django==3.1.4
psycopg2==2.8.6
postgres (PostgreSQL) 13.1 (Debian 13.1-1.pgdg100+1)
```

I'm testing with a clone of production database.

1. SELECT query for a problematic data.

```
TEST=# SELECT issued_at FROM table_name WHERE id = 153;
           issued_at
-------------------------------
 2021-06-18 10:10:49.075392+00
(1 row)
```

2. In `python manage.py shell`, retrieve data with `connections.cursor()`

```
>>> with transaction.atomic():
...     query = f'''SELECT issued_at FROM table_name WHERE id = 153;'''
...     with connections['test_db'].cursor() as cursor: 
...             cursor.execute(query)
...             print(cursor.fetchone())
...
(datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 18, 10, 10, 49, 753920, tzinfo=<UTC>),)
```

---

Addition 2.

When I get data with django's `Model.objects.get()`, the result comes out good.

```
>>> data = TableName.objects.get(id=153)
>>> data.issued_at
datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 18, 10, 10, 49, 75392, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

It seems a kind of problem of `django.db.connections`.

Comment: This looks like a potential bug. You can perhaps create a ticket for this: https://code.djangoproject.com/newticket

Comment: the values are sent as numbers to the database, not as strings. you can store them in string and then insert them.

Comment: @NikhilB: yes, but the point is that reading and writing should be each others inverse: if you write some timestamp to the db, you expect to read the same value back. Here that is not the case, which is quite *odd*.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you. I wll create one if it turns out to be a bug. I'm on testing it a bit more now.

Comment: It was a stupid question. I did a mistake on retrieving the data. Sorry all and thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not seeing it:

```
CREATE TABLE public.dt_test (
    id integer,
    ts_fld timestamp without time zone,
    tsz_fld timestamp with time zone
);
insert into dt_test values (1, '2021-06-07 09:22:13.099866+00', '2021-06-07 09:22:13.099866+00');
insert into dt_test values (2, '2021-06-07 09:22:13.99866+00', '2021-06-07 09:22:13.99866+00');
select * from dt_test ;
 id |           ts_fld           |            tsz_fld            
----+----------------------------+-------------------------------
  1 | 2021-06-07 09:22:13.099866 | 2021-06-07 02:22:13.099866-07
  2 | 2021-06-07 09:22:13.99866  | 2021-06-07 02:22:13.99866-07

import psycopg2 
cur.execute('select * from dt_test')
rs = cur.fetchall()
rs                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[23]: 
[(1,
  datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 7, 9, 22, 13, 99866),
  datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 7, 2, 22, 13, 99866, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=-420, name=None))),
 (2,
  datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 7, 9, 22, 13, 998660),
  datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 7, 2, 22, 13, 998660, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=-420, name=None)))]
cur.execute('insert into dt_test(id, ts_fld) values(%s, %s)', [3, datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 7, 9, 22, 13, 99866)])
con.commit()
 select * from dt_test ;
 id |           ts_fld           |            tsz_fld            
----+----------------------------+-------------------------------
  1 | 2021-06-07 09:22:13.099866 | 2021-06-07 02:22:13.099866-07
  2 | 2021-06-07 09:22:13.99866  | 2021-06-07 02:22:13.99866-07
  3 | 2021-06-07 09:22:13.099866 | NULL
```

What you are seeing is normalization to 1000000:

```
select 998660/1000000.0;
        ?column?        
------------------------
 0.99866000000000000000

select 99866/1000000.0;
        ?column?        
------------------------
 0.09986600000000000000
```

Comment: Wow... sorry it was my misunderstand about it. Thank you I will try it again.

Comment: Hmm seems a bit different with my test. Can I get your version infos?
I'm testing on postgres v13.1. 
```postgres (PostgreSQL) 13.1 (Debian 13.1-1.pgdg100+1)```, 
```Django==3.1.4``` and ```psycopg2==2.8.6```.

Comment: I have tried with `psycopg2 2.8.5 and 2.91` and `postgres 12.7 and 13.0`. I get the same results. Add to your question the exact steps you are taking in your test and the results that are returned. For now I would leave out `Django`. Also add the `Python` version you are using.

Comment: It is ```Python 3.9.1```. I've modified the question. It seems ```django.db.connections``` object has something wrong.

Comment: I find that hard to believe as the underlying driver is the same and that is the part doing the type conversions. Are you sure `connections['test_db']` is actually pointing at what you think it is?

Comment: Yes, ```connections['test_db']``` indicates the database I'm using. This django project uses multi databases. As the data retrieved from the codes are actually the data I wanna retrieve, ```connections['test_db']``` points exactly what I want.

Comment: And you have looked in the `DATABASES = ` section of `settings.py` to confirm this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233970/discussion-between-dobyek-and-adrian-klaver).